# How to ensure that reading is being done on Secondary only?

Tags: mongodb

I have created a replica set with 3 servers ( primary , secondary and arbitery )

I am using Java with mongodb .

This is my below method , for querying the MongoDB data .

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("symbol", "" + symbol);
ReadPreference preference = ReadPreference.secondary();
DBCursor cursor = new DBCursor(coll, query, null, preference);
```

**My question is that , How to ensure that i am getting the data from Secondary only but not from primary ??**

Comment: that should do it if I understand the java correctly

Comment: thank you , any proof on to the mongo side  level ??

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondary